# How to remove splash screen about prism

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, prism

When I start an app, created with the Blank Prism template for Xamarin, on Android I get a brief splash saying Prism Library, how do one remove this splash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I should have looked in the android project and not just the shared.
You change this within \MyProject.Android\Resources\drawable\splash_screen.xml